# Как отправлять письма с pdd.yandex с аватаркой

Tags: email, smtp, яндекс-почта

Прикрепил свой домен к яндексу, вида info@mysite.ru
Вся почта работает без проблем, но письма приходят без аватарки. В яндекс.паспорте аватарка установлена. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отправлять письма с аватаркой? Может какой-то дополнительный заголовок нужно прописать? Пробовал Face

Answer (score 0):

Добавить аватарку для созданного сотрудника, он же почтовый ящик (вариант для connect, поскольку сейчас яндекс всех с pdd переводит туда. Если старый интерфейс, ситуация скорее всего аналогичная).

После установки, аватарка появляется через какое-то время в письмах, отправленных от этого ящика.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но я же в самом вопросе написал, что уже сделал это и пусто

Comment: Значит подождите и отправьте письмо ещё раз от этого юзера. Яндекс не сразу аватарку ставит. Но то, что после этого действия она появляется - факт (буквально 2-3 дня назад клиенту SMTP настраивал и заодно аккаунт - всё работало).